# Referencing parent selectors using the ampersand character, and :not

Tags: css, sass

The article [here](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand) shows a brilliant example of using an ampersand to reference a parent selector, like so:

```
h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  .some-parent-selector & {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

This works as expected. However, I am following BEM principles and do not wish to have overriding Sass. As you can see in my screenshot below, the styles from `.js-tabby` overrides the default `.tabs` code.

[image]

I've tried things like:

```
.tabs {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;

  .js-tabby &:not(&) {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .js-tabby & {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

But alas, it doesn't work.

Comment: Of *course* there would be downvotes, this *is* SO after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing this question, I had a thought that seemed crazy, but it worked! So, here's my first Q&A **ever**:

```
.tabs {    
  html:not(.js-tabby) & {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  html.js-tabby & {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

The plugin I'm using attaches the `.js-tabby` class to the `html` element, so I targeted that and BOOM! It works.

This has been something that's plagued me for so long, and I hope I can save someone else further frustration.